# run function on each row which returns multiple rows R

Tags: r, plyr

After much experimenting and googling... and subsequent experimenting again, I am finally resulting to asking my first question on StackOverflow :)

I have a data.frame, and want to apply a custom function, `expandBases`, to each row of the data.frame. `expandBases` returns a data.frame consisting of 1 or more rows (and this will vary depending on the data supplied to it). `expandBases` actually returns more columns than in the toy example below -- but for the sake of illustration:

```
structure(list(id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
startpos = c(1, 2, 3), len = c(1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("id",
"startpos", "len"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")


expandBases <- function(startpos, len)
{
    return(data.frame(cy <- startpos + 0:(len - 1)))
}
```

I would like the `id` factor to be replicated for each row of the returned data.frame. I've been told to use lapply + do.call(rbind). I was wondering if there is a plyr-based solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is. I know my answer to the immediately prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895796/r-separating-strings-and-linking-them-to-another-column does this and maybe @csgillespie 's does as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to guess slightly at exactly what you want, but here is how to go about using base R (`do.call` + `lapply`) as well as `plyr`:

The helper function that creates the data frame:

```
expandBases <- function(x){
  with(x, 
    data.frame(
      id = rep(id, len-1),
      cy = startpos + seq_len(len-1)
      )
   )
}
```

Using base R:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(i)expandBases(dat[i, ])))
  id cy
1  b  3
2  c  4
3  c  5
```

Using plyr:

```
library(plyr)
adply(dat, 1, expandBases)[-(1:2)]
  id cy
1  b  3
2  c  4
3  c  5
```

---

Note that I implemented the function as you described in your question, but that means one row always goes missing.  I suspect that's not quite what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I just realised my example was slightly wrong - and just updated it. Either way, your solution is what I wanted, and very easy to follow. Thank you for providing both examples!

Comment: Also -- I think id should be repeated 'len' times -- is this why one of the rows goes missing?

Comment: @Lauren Yes, I believe so. `len` instead of `len - 1`